# Lucene.NET - Fuzzy Search - Finding Matching Requests

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, indexing, lucene.net

I have an index store which contains various phrases but some are mispelt, e.g.: -

```
"Hallo World"
"Qick Brown Fox"
"Long tame no sees"
```

I am running a fuzzy search using a boolean queries but if there are matches I have no idea how to retrieve the phrases which matched. I don't just want the phrase from the index store which I can get easily.

e.g. If my search is a boolean query of ("Hello World" or "Keep it Real" or "Long Time no See") it will return "Hallo World" and "Long tame no sees".
However I also need to know that my original phrases, "Hello World" and "Long Time no See" were matched. Any ideas? My Search method is below (currently returning phrase matches but the mispelt ones): -

```
public IEnumerable<DocumentWrapper> Search(List<string> fieldsToSearch, List<string> phrases, string path)
{

    var luceneDir = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(path));

    if (luceneDir == null)
    {
        Logging.Error("Invalid Index Directory during Search");
        return null;
    }
    Logging.Information(string.Format("Searching for phrase(s): {0}", phrases.ToSeparatedList()));


    var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
    IndexReader indexReader;
    try
    {
        indexReader = IndexReader.Open(luceneDir, true);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        Logging.Error("Lucene Directory has no items");
        return null;
    }


    var matchedDocuments = new List<DocumentWrapper>();
    try
    {
        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
        MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = null;
        if (fieldsToSearch != null)
        {
            queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, fieldsToSearch.ToArray(), analyzer);
        }
        else
        {
            queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30,
                                                    indexReader.GetFieldNames(
                                                        IndexReader.FieldOption.INDEXED_NO_TERMVECTOR).ToArray(),
                                                    analyzer);
        }

        //Add a fuzzy search using a tilde on each word in the phrase then 'AND' them together.
        var booleanQueries = new List<BooleanQuery>();
        foreach (var phrase in phrases)
        {
            var terms = phrase.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
            foreach (var term in terms)
            {
                booleanQuery.Add(queryParser.Parse(term.Replace("~", "") + "~"), Occur.MUST);
                    //'AND' the words in the phrase together.
            }
            booleanQueries.Add(booleanQuery);
        }

        //combine our boolean queries with 'OR' i.e. (word1 and word2 and word3) OR (word4 and word5) OR (word 6)
        var combined = new BooleanQuery();
        foreach (var query in booleanQueries)
        {
            combined.Add(query, Occur.SHOULD);
        }


        var maxHits = 100; //TODO - configurable
        var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(maxHits, true);
        searcher.Search(combined, collector);
        var hits = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;


        foreach (var t in hits)
        {
            var hitDoc = searcher.Doc(t.Doc);
            var indexDoc = new DocumentWrapper();
            foreach (var field in hitDoc.GetFields())
            {
                if (field.Name == "Score")
                {
                    indexDoc.Contents.Add(field.Name, t.Score);
                }
                else
                {
                    indexDoc.Contents.Add(field.Name, hitDoc.Get(field.Name));
                }
            }
            matchedDocuments.Add(indexDoc);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //TODO - Logging?
    }

    return matchedDocuments;
}
```

Comment: If you need to know which phrase matches which query, the solution would be to simply run them as separate searches.  Sounds like you need three datasets, one with fuzzy matches to "Hello World", on with fuzzy matches on "Keep it Real", on with fuzzy matches on "Long Time No See".  Or whatever other `phrases` are passed into the method.

Comment: It seems more like a wildcard-query than fuzzy-query

Comment: Thanks for your answer femtoRgon. That's how I was doing it before, but I was concerned about a reduction in performance. There are going to be 50 defined phrases so I would have to run 50 searches. Do you think there would be a speed difference?

I4V, I'm append the tidle to each word in the phrase to make it fuzzy then ANDing them together, then at the end I'm ORing all queries together.

Comment: I timed it with just 5 phrases: 1200ms for 5 separate searches and 500ms for 1 search. That's going to be an enormous difference for 50 searches.

Comment: And if you don't need to know which query generated which results, it's a great way to go.  But there isn't really an easy way to determine which query term gave rise to which result.  I would first try improving performance by setting a minimum fuzzy prefix length [StandardQueryParser.setFuzzyPrefixLength](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/standard/StandardQueryParser.html#setFuzzyPrefixLength(int)).  It might pay to experiement with the FuzzyMinSim, as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I took your advice. I managed to get the searching to be a lot quicker.